# Stereopairs datasaet with calibration information

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

Can you give me stereo pairs dataset with camera calibration information? That has Q matrix that I need for OpenCV [reprojectImageTo3D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=reprojectimageto3d#cv.ReprojectImageTo3D) function or has such information that I can construct Q matrix. Or at least dataset with focal length in mm and baseline info, that I can write custom reprojection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086878/can-you-recommend-a-source-of-reference-data-for-fundamental-matrix-calculation/19282852#19282852

Comment: @DaveDurbin: Where is it duplicate? Middlebury datasets don't have Q matrix, and I know about it.

Comment: From OpenCV docs `The matrix Q can be an arbitrary 4 × 4 matrix (for example, the one computed by stereoRectify()).` i.e. There's no particular Q matrix. If you want to construct one, you can use `stereoRectify()` which requires intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters which are available with the Middleburg dataset I believe

Comment: I know about that, but middleberry datasets doesn't have enough info for stereoRectify, it has no neither Rotation and Translation matrix nor disortion coefficients. I do custom reprojection using this dataset. But it is not my question answer

Comment: From http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/data/. name_par.txt: camera parameters. There is one line for each image. The format for each line is: "imgname.png k11 k12 k13 k21 k22 k23 k31 k32 k33 r11 r12 r13 r21 r22 r23 r31 r32 r33 t1 t2 t3". The projection matrix for